# Qt/C++ physics engine similar to iOS UIKit Dynamics

Tags: ios, c++, qt

I was wondering if there are any tools for simulating physical movement for animations in `Qt`. I remember I once saw on `iOS` that one could drag a panel down faster and the panel would bounce on the bottom of the screen with an intensity proportionally with the force it was dragged with; i believe it's called [UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/206/). Something like this:

[image]

Or let's say I wish to create this type of bouncing effect for my UI:

[image]

Here the progress circle elapsed value is slightly bouncing after reaching its new value. These effects can't be done just with easing curves Qt animations offer.

Does anyone know if there are ways to create these types of animations with `Qt Widgets` or `Qt Quick`? Is there something there which could be integrated with `Qt Animations`?